# what does xhr status code 408 error mean in jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am making ajax calls with jquery like this

http://pastie.org/860837

and sometimes i get the ajax errors, and i get xhr status as 408. what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

408 is really an [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status#4xx_Client_Error), and it means that your request timed out:

> **408 Request Timeout**
>
> The server timed out waiting for the request.[2] According to W3 HTTP specifications:
>   "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to 
>   wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time."

Answer (score 0):

Its a Request Timeout

> The client did not produce a request
>   within the time that the server was
>   prepared to wait. The client MAY
>   repeat the request without
>   modifications at any later time.

See **[HTTP/1.1 Status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)**